# Why does this function return the wrong results?

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why when I try out this function with this particular example: **is_valid_sequence('ABCDEFG')**, it comes up "True" instead of "False"? I am completely new to programming in general. This is for an online course I'm taking. Thanks.

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna_sequence):
    ''' (str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if DNA sequence is made up of 'A', 'T', 'C', and 'G' nucleotides.

    >>> is_valid_sequence('ATCGGC')
    True
    >>> is_valid_sequence('aTcGGc')
    False
    >>> is_valid_sequence('ABCDEFG')
    False

    '''    

    for char in dna_sequence:
        if char not in 'ACTG':
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 11):

You are returning too early. Try this

```
for char in dna_sequence:
    if char not in 'ACTG':
        return False
return True
```

or more simply

```
return all(char in 'ACTG' for char in dna_sequence)
```

Comment: `all` is perhaps more pythonic.

Comment: Upvoted for 'all', and all I can say is wow!  Sunday midnight, and 6 responses before my answer is submitted -- all within 8 minutes.  I'm gonna just sit back and wait henceforth ...

Answer (score 3):

Your method will exit at the *first* character that matches. Since the first character of `ABCDEFG` is a valid character, your method return `True`.

You need to go through the entire string and see if *all* characters match.

Answer (score 2):

Because you use `return` only the first `char` gets tested.

Simple correction:

```
res = True
for ch in dna_sequence:
    if ch not in 'ACTG':
        res &= False # or return as you know it's false
    else:
        res &= True
return res
```

But there are more "pythonic" way to do this, take a look at the [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) function for example

Comment: Yes, I imagined this was the problem. But how do I fix it?

Comment: Would you really use `&=` like that? BTW you forgot to return `res`

Comment: No, that was for the explanation, I would go with all()

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that as soon as it hits the `A`, it returns True. Your logic needs to not return until it hits either an invalid character or the end of the string:

```
    for char in dna_sequence:
        if char not in 'ACTG':
            return False
    # we hit the end of the string, so it must be valid
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

return causes an exit of the function regardless of anything this will only check one character

```
for char in dna_sequence:
    if char not in 'ACTG':
        return False
return true # after whole string checked
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you're returning True if the first value matches, rather than examining all the values.  Corrected code:

```
for char in dna_sequence:
    if char not in 'ACTG':
        return False
return True
```